# Recent and pinned files and folders do not open when selected from taskbar icon right-click menu

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, taskbar, icons

### Background

Pinning applications to the taskbar is working fine. When you right-click on a taskbar icon, you see recently-opened and pinned files and folders (e.g. I have Downloads pinned to the File Explorer taskbar icon)

### The Problem

Clicking on one of these recent or pinned items should open it, but nothing happens when I click it. Clicking the taskbar icon does open the program.

### What I've Tried:

- Removing the pinned item, re-opening it, and re-pinning the recent file
- Recent items and pinned items
- 8 different taskbar icons, both pinned and recent items

[image: Picture of taskbar icon with recent files]

Comment: Was the recent or pinned item you were trying to open perhaps moved to a different location or deleted? They appear in the jump list in the first place if it's been opened before in that application, so it could be possible that the system could not find the item in its original location.

Comment: No that is not the problem, but thank you. I have tried removing the pinned item, re-opening it, and re-pinning the recent file, and it still does not open.